# Get folder by FolderId to find parent folder

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Is there an easy way to get a folder by its folder id?

I have an item which has the property `item.ParentFolderId` but I can't find any method like `GetFolderById(id)` or something like that.

I actually searched a lot in the MSDN library but I wasn't successful.

Comment: I think you're searching for [Folder.Bind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd634177(v=exchg.80).aspx) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ExchangeService.FindFolders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.findfolders%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) to search for sub-folders

Or as diiN suggested [Folder.Bind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.folder.bind%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) to bind to exisiting folder

Comment: Thank you! Not very intuitive that I can't access the folder directly through the item in my opinion.

Comment: Any chance of some sample code how to do this using `Folder.Bind` please?